# Read from kafka producer console and write to a file

Tags: python, apache-kafka

How can I read from a kafka producer console and write a text file using python?

I have tried the following steps:

1. start zookeeper.
2. start kafka server.
3. created a topic 'test'.
4. start kafka producer and consumer console.
5. Wrote a python file with the following code:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('test',bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])

# filename = 'test.txt'
# file = open(filename,'w')

# for messages in consumer:
#     file.write(messages.value.decode('utf-8') + '\n')

# file.close()

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for message in consumer:
        f.write(message.value.decode('utf-8') + '\n')

f.close()
```

When I run the python file and write something in the kafka producer console, it does not show up in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka consumers are endless, so your file will never close/flush to have data written to it.

You will want to try stopping your consumer after a certain number of messages, or otherwise flush the file handle with the same, while writing